# Mobile Detection in website using nginx

Tags: php, linux, cookies, nginx, mobile

I have problem with website that not detect mobile version when people try to surf the website from their phones

when i use Apache the code works as well , this problem only happen using nginx

This is the PHP code i use to detect visitor either using desktop or mobile

```
if($_COOKIE['detect_mobiles'] == 1)
{
    $settings['template'] = 'smartphone';

}elseif($_COOKIE['detect_mobiles'] == 2)
{

}else{

    if(preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
               $settings['template'] = 'smartphone';


        setcookie('detect_mobiles','1',time()+(60200),'/');
        setcookie('detect_mobiles2','3',time()+(60200),'/');

    }else
    {

        setcookie('detect_mobiles','2',time()+(60200),'/');

    }
}
```

this is my nginx configuration

**Custom Rules**

```
set $PROXY_DOMAIN_OR_IP "192.168.1.1";
```

**Default.conf**

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server; # Uncomment if your server supports IPv6

    server_name localhost;

    # deny all; # DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS LINE - Used when Engintron is disabled to block Nginx from becoming an open proxy

    set $PROXY_DOMAIN_OR_IP $host;

    # Set custom rules like domain/IP exclusions or redirects here
    include custom_rules;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        include proxy_params_common;
        # === MICRO CACHING ===
        # Comment the following line to disable 1 second micro-caching for dynamic HTML content
        include proxy_params_dynamic;
    }

    # Enable browser cache for static content files (TTL is 1 hour)
    location ~* \.(?:json|xml|rss|atom)$ {
        include proxy_params_common;
        include proxy_params_static;
        expires 60s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        access_log off;
    }

    # Enable browser cache for CSS / JS (TTL is 30 days)
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        include proxy_params_common;
        include proxy_params_static;
        expires 60s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        access_log off;
    }

    # Enable browser cache for media & document files (TTL is 60 days)
    location ~* \.(?:ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|webp|tiff|mp3|flac|ogg|mid|midi|wav|wma|mp4|mov|3gp|webm|mkv|ogv|wmv|zip|7z|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|tar|exe|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|rtf|odt|ods|odp)$ {
        include proxy_params_common;
        include proxy_params_static;
        expires 60s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        access_log off;
    }

    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

**proxy_params_common**

```
# General Proxy Settings
proxy_pass          http://$PROXY_DOMAIN_OR_IP:8080;
proxy_http_version  1.1;                # Always upgrade to HTTP/1.1
proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding ""; # Optimize encoding
proxy_set_header    Connection "";      # Enable keepalives
proxy_set_header    Host $host;
proxy_set_header    Proxy "";
proxy_set_header    Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    CF-Connecting-IP $http_cf_connecting_ip;
proxy_set_header    Cf-Visitor $http_cf_visitor;

# Buffers
proxy_buffers                 256 16k;
proxy_buffer_size             128k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size       256k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size    256k;

# Timeouts
proxy_connect_timeout         120s;
proxy_read_timeout            180s;
proxy_send_timeout            180s;

# Info
add_header                    X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
add_header                    X-Server-Powered-By "Engintron";
```

**proxy_params_dynamic**

```
set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC "1s";

# CMS (& CMS extension) specific cookies (Joomla, K2, WordPress)
if ($http_cookie ~* "joomla_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|userID|comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}

# Invision Power Board (IPB)
if ($cookie_member_id ~ "^[1-9][0-9]*$") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}

# Admin sections & generic entry point names for CMSs
if ($request_uri ~* "/administrator|/wp-admin|/wp-login.php|/ucp.php|/login|/connect") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}

# Generic query string to request a page bypassing Nginx's caching
if ($query_string ~* "nocache") {
    set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;
    set $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC 0;
}

proxy_no_cache          $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC;
proxy_cache_bypass      $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC;

proxy_cache             engintron_dynamic;
proxy_cache_key         "$request_method$scheme$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_lock        on;
proxy_cache_methods     GET HEAD;
proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504; # Additional options: http_403 http_404
proxy_cache_valid       200 1s; # Adjust for longer cache times (unfortunately, we cannot use a variable here)
proxy_ignore_headers    Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie Vary;

# Headers
expires                 $EXPIRES_FOR_DYNAMIC;
add_header              Pragma "public";
add_header              Cache-Control "public";
add_header              Vary "Accept-Encoding";
```

**proxy_params_static**

```
proxy_cache                 engintron_static;
proxy_cache_key             "$request_method$scheme$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_lock            on;
proxy_cache_min_uses        1;
proxy_cache_revalidate      on;
proxy_cache_use_stale       error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504; # Additional options: http_403 http_404
proxy_cache_valid           200 301 302 1m; # Covers 200, 301 & 302 responses, caching time set to 1 minute
proxy_ignore_headers        Set-Cookie;
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ## Basic Settings ##
    client_body_timeout             20s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
    client_header_timeout           20s; # Use 5s for high-traffic sites
    client_max_body_size            1024m;
    keepalive_timeout               20s;
    port_in_redirect                off;
    sendfile                        on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_tokens                   off;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    types_hash_max_size             2048;

    ## DNS Resolver ##
    # If in China, enable the OpenDNS entry that matches your network connectivity (IPv4 only or IPv4 & IPv6)
    # OpenDNS (IPv4 & IPv6)
    #resolver                       208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 [2620:0:ccc::2] [2620:0:ccd::2];
    # OpenDNS (IPv4 only)
    #resolver                       208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220;
    # Google Public DNS (IPv4 & IPv6)
    #resolver                       8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 [2001:4860:4860::8888] [2001:4860:4860::8844];
    # Google Public DNS (IPv4 only) [default]
    resolver                        8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

    # CloudFlare
    # List from: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4
    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
    # List from: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
    set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
    set_real_ip_from   192.168.1.4;
    # Replace with correct visitor IP
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    ## MIME ##
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ## Logging Settings ##
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ## Gzip Settings ##
    gzip on;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-javascript
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy
        text/x-js
        text/xml;
    gzip_vary on;

    # Proxy Settings
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/engintron_dynamic levels=1:2 keys_zone=engintron_dynamic:20m inactive=10m max_size=500m;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/engintron_static levels=1:2 keys_zone=engintron_static:20m inactive=10m max_size=500m;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/engintron_temp;

    ## Virtual Host Configs ##
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

.htaccess for main website

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index19.html$ infodmca.php [L]
RewriteRule ^feed.php rss.php?r=film&l=10 [L]
RewriteRule ^confirmaccount-([0-9]+)-(.*).html?$ profile.php?a=confirm_account&u=$1&code=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^confirmemail-([0-9]+)-(.*).html?$ login.php?a=confirm_email&u=$1&code=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^lostpassword.html?$ login.php?a=lost_password [L]
RewriteRule ^registrer.html?$ profile.php?a=register [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/.+\.html$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editavatar.html?$ usercp.php?a=avatar [L]
RewriteRule ^editprofil.html?$ usercp.php?a=profile [L]
RewriteRule ^emailpassword.html?$ usercp.php?a=emailpassword [L]
RewriteRule ^modifieroptions.html?$ usercp.php?a=options [L]
RewriteRule ^usercp.html?$ usercp.php [L]
RewriteRule ^infodmca.html?$ infodmca.php [L]
RewriteRule ^infomentions.html?$ infomentions.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contacternous.html?$ contacternous.php [L]
RewriteRule ^friends.html?$ usercp.php?a=friends [L]
RewriteRule ^composemessages.html?$ privatemessages.php?a=compose [L]
RewriteRule ^messagesenvoye.html?$ privatemessages.php?f=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^privatemessages.html?$ privatemessages.php [L]
RewriteRule ^favoris.html?$ usercp.php?a=favorites [L]
RewriteRule ^posterserie/(.*)$ posterserie/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php?type=film [L]
RewriteRule ^tag-(.*).html$ taaags.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-saison-([0-9]+)-episode-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).htm$ episode.php?episode&id=$1&saison=$2&episode=$3&idepisode=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-saison-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).htm$ saison.php?id=$1&saison=$2&idsaison=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^serie/(.*).htm$ serie.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^anime/(.*)/episode-(.*)-([0-9]+).htm$ episodeanime.php?id=$1&episode=$2&idepisode=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^anime/(.*).htm$ anime.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/hebergeur-(.*)/(.*)$ seriehebergeur.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/hebergeur-(.*) seriehebergeur.php?chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/annee-(.*)/(.*)$ seriesannee.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/annee-(.*) seriesannee.php?chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/alphabet/(.*)/(.*)$ seriealphabet.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/alphabet/(.*) seriealphabet.php?&chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ pagefilm.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^alphabet/(.*)/(.*)$ alphabet.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^nationalite/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ nationalite.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^realisateur/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ realisateur.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmsemaine/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ filmweek.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmlangue/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ languefilm.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmqualite/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ qualitefilm.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmformat/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ formatfilm.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^acteur/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ acteur.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^series/nationalite/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ seriesnationalite.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/acteur/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ seriesacteur.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^filmshebergeur/uptobox$ badlinkhebergeur.php [L]

RewriteRule ^films/annee-(.*)/(.*)$ annee.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmshebergeur/(.*)/(.*)$ hebergeur.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/(.*)_1$ seriegenre.php?ngenre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/(.*)_(.*)$ seriegenre.php?ngenre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/(.*)_1$ animegenre.php?ngenre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/(.*)_(.*)$ animegenre.php?ngenre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^film-comedie$ genre.php?ngenre=comedie&page=1 [L]




RewriteRule ^film-streaming-(.*)_1$ genre.php?ngenre=$1&page=1&li=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_1$ genre.php?ngenre=$1&page=1&li=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ genre.php?ngenre=$1&page=$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^alphabet/(.*) alphabet.php?chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^films/annee-(.*) annee.php?chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^filmshebergeur/(.*) hebergeur.php?chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hebergeur-uptobox$ hebergeur.php?chiffre=uptobox [L]
RewriteRule ^ajouter_film.html index.php?go=ajouterfilms [L]
RewriteRule ^ajouter_part.html index.php?go=addpart [L]
RewriteRule ^contacternous$ index.php?go=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^demander$ demander.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout.html login.php?a=logout [L]
RewriteRule ^inscription.html index.php?go=inscription [L]
RewriteRule ^films.html index.php?go=films [L]
RewriteRule ^topfilm(.*) index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^lesfilms(.*) touslesfilms.php?page=$1&li=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^film-en-streaming-p2 touslesfilms.php?page=2&li=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^film-en-streaming-p7 touslesfilms.php?page=7&li=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^film-en-streaming touslesfilms.php?page=1 [L]



RewriteRule ^series/page-(.*)$ lesseries.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^series/ lesseries2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^series-tv/ lesseries2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^series-tv-streaming/ lesseries.php [L]
RewriteRule ^seriestv/ lesseries2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/alphabet/(.*)/(.*)$ alphabetanime.php?chiffre=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/alphabet/(.*) alphabetanime.php?&chiffre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/populaire/page-(.*)$ populaireanime.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/populaire/ populaireanime.php [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/dernier/page-(.*)$ dernieranime.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/dernier/ dernieranime.php [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/page-(.*)$ lesanimes.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^animes/ lesanimes.php [L]
RewriteRule ^khalid(.*) index.php?go=filmstreaminge&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)lesfilmde(.*).html index.php?go=filmuser&user=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^prochainement.html index.php?go=prochainement [L]
RewriteRule ^prochainement(.*).html index.php?go=prochainement&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^top_films.html index.php?go=top_films [L]
RewriteRule ^selection.html index.php?go=selection [L]
RewriteRule ^selection(.*).html index.php?go=selection&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rechercher search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+) index.php?go=rechercher2&tags=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^message.html index.php?go=message [L]
RewriteRule ^member(.*).html index.php?go=member&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^configuration.html index.php?go=configuration [L]
RewriteRule ^Gerer_Film(.*).html index.php?go=config_article&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editfilm(.*).html index.php?go=editfilm&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^modifercomp index.php?go=modifercomp [L]
RewriteRule ^pass_oublie.html index.php?go=pass_oublie [L]
RewriteRule ^Confirmation-(.*) index.php?go=Confirmation&t=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^auto_ajouter index.php?go=auto_ajouter [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/rss.xml rssgenre.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml rss.php?r=film&l=10 [L]
RewriteRule ^najouter(.*).html index.php?go=najouter&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^marecherche(.*).html index.php?go=marecherche&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^partenaire.html part.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap(.*).html index.php?go=sitemape&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^urllist.txt index.php?go=urliste1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Comment: thats a lot of code. can you tell me more about what the problem is so i don't have to debug from scratch (not going to happen)?

Comment: the problem is the php code for mobile detection not work with nginx i am running in server , if i removed the nginx i got the code worked on website well so the problem with nginx configuration and i dunno what is problem exactly with nginx